# Deleting a character at specified index position in a string using python

Tags: python

I'm trying to delete a character from a string with a chosen index position. Why is my code not working?

```
st = "hello"
n = int(input())
def drop_n(st, n):
    if n <= len(st) or n == len(st):
        return (st.pop(n))
    else:
        return "String to small or number too big"
```

Comment: FYI: `n <= len(st) or n == len(st)` doesn't make sense - `n <= len(st)` *means* `n < len(st) or n == len(st)`

Comment: If you want to return the popped character, turn the st into an iterable before using `pop` on it.

Comment: Do you want to return the new string with the character deleted, or the character that was removed (popped)?

Comment: i want to return a new string with the character deleted

Comment: Give us the desired output or we won't be able to help you.

Comment: Please, do note that "why it is  not working" is not a detailed description of the actual behavior of your code. You should not only describe what your desired behavior is, but also what you think is wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`pop` does not operate on a string, but even if it did it would return the item it deleted.  There are several ways to do this, one, using `pop`, creates a list then converts back to a string:

```
st = "hello"
n = int(input())

def drop_n(st, n):
    if n < len(st):      # note the change to this.  
        it = list(st)
        char = it.pop(n)
        return ''.join(it)
    else:
        return "String too small or number too big"

print(drop_n(st, n))
```

Note that negative indices are valid.  `n == len(st)` would go beyond the bounds of the list, since indices count from zero.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just index the string?

```
st = "hello"
n = int(input('enter index to delete: '))

def drop_n(st, n):
    if n < abs(len(st)):
        return st[:n] + st[n+1:]
    else:
        return "index out of range"
```